# filter item by id using react router return empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, react-router

I am using react router...route path: /product/:id

I am trying to filter item by id to that matches with url but it's returning nothing...could you guys help me?

```
import React from 'react'


function SelectedProduct(props) {

  const { id } = props.match.params
  console.log(id) 
  console.log(props.product)

  const filtered = props.product.filter(product => product.id === props.match.params.id)
  console.log(filtered)

  return (
    <div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default SelectedProduct
```

[Console.log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMuji.png)

Comment: If its logging empty array so it mean no elements in `props.product` have id equal to
`props.match.params.id`.Try using `==` instead of `===`

Answer (score 1):

May be the id in your number is an integer and you are equalizing it to a string? Can you try the below code?

```
const filtered = props.product.filter(product => parseInt(product.id, 10) === parseInt(props.match.params.id, 10))
console.log(filtered)
```